# SPFx version in SharePoint 2019 On Premise

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

Anyone knows which version om SPFx will be available in SharePoint Server 2019 on premise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SharePoint Server 2019 will ship with SPFx version `1.4.1`.

Vesa Juvonen, Senior Project Manager for SharePoint, mentioned this in one of the events a few days back.

Since SP 2019 will have inbuilt support for modern team(not connected to O365 groups though) and communication sites, the SPFx extensions will also work here.